# Cannot connect to MySql database after updating MySql.Data .NET package to a version newer than 8.0.27

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, mysql.data

I am using the MySql.Data package in a .NET Framework 4.7.2 application.

When updating MySql.Data to a version newer than 8.0.27, the database connection fails in a previously working project with no other changes. At the time of writing this includes MySql.Data versions: 8.0.28 to 8.0.31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not mentioned in the [release notes for 8.0.28](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-net/en/news-8-0-28.html), it seems the default SSL mode was changed.

Specifying the `SSL Mode` in the connection string solved the issue. In my case this was for a local MySql server installation and I used: `SSL Mode=None;`

Comment: It's probably worth taking the time to get SSL working.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Do you think it's necessary for a local machine connection? I'm figuring, if you have local access to the point of being able to monitor the connection like that, all is lost anyway?

Comment: Necessary? No. But in some places that doesn't matter. For example, many industries have regulatory requirements for data to be encrypted both in transit and at rest.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn A worthwhile consideration, thank you.